# Session cookie without http flag

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, session-cookies, setcookie

Just received the results of a security audit - everything clear apart from two things

- Session cookie without http flag.
- Session cookie without secure flag set.

So how I can set the httpOnly flag and secure flag through jQuery?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and the results from that. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot set those types of cookies with jQuery. You can only set those on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Both needs to be configured at server before issuing cookie. You can read more about the security issues otherwise from [OWASP documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)